Problem with .Net on Windows: Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
I am developing a Windows app using C#/.Net, which writes log files into
a subfolder in the AppData folder.
During development on my local machine, everything is fine and the log files are stored in my AppData folder
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MyProgram\Logs

However, when I deploy the application using msix, and install it on another machine, the AppData folder (sometimes) is relocated:
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Local\Packages\<PackageName>\LocalCache\MyProgram\Logs

Writing the log files still works fine.
Now, I want to create a command which allows the user to open the logfile-folder in the Windows-Explorer for convenience. I wrote the following code:
string logPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
    "MyProgramm",
    "Logs");
        
var logDir = new DirectoryInfo(logPath);
if (logDir.Exists) {
    Debug.WriteLine($"Folder = '{logDir.FullName}'");
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(logDir.FullName) {
        UseShellExecute = true
     });
 }

This works fine during development, but not after deployment.
The condition if(logDir.Exists) is true, the debug output is still
Folder = 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MyProgram\Logs'

although the app writes to the relocated AppData folder.
Starting the external process, however, reports, that the folder does not exist (which is true, because the app uses the relocated path)
My question is: Is there any way to obtain the real path on the local hard drive for Windows-Explorer to open? I have tried PhysicalDirectoryInfo instead of DirectoryInfo, but without success.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

MSIX Flexible Virtualization: "provides a way for your app to declare that some set of its files and Registry entries should be visible to other apps; and that those should persist on app uninstall. All other files and Registry entries are not visible to other apps; and are removed on uninstall."

Thank you for pointing me to this resource! It will solve my problem in a different way as expected.
